# Using Powershell to download list of files and incrementally name downloads

Tags: powershell, download, batch-rename

I have a list of URLs for xml files saved in list.txt. I want to use list.txt to download the URLs and  save them with incremental filenames: download1.xml, download2.xml, etc. How do I achieve this with Powershell?

I have the following code snippet as a starting point - this achieves the download from list, but not the incremental naming. Any help much appreciated.

```
$object = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$lists = get-content C:\list.txt
$downdir = "C:\Download\"
foreach($list in $lists)
{
    $filename = $list.split('/'); 

    $object.DownloadFile($list, $downdir+$filename[$filename.count-1])
}
```

Also is there a way to send all the download requests at 5 second intervals rather than waiting for each single download to complete before sending the next request? My knowledge is limited, so specifics would be a big help. Many thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
object = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$lists = get-content C:\list.txt
$downdir = "C:\Download\"
$i = 1
foreach($list in $lists)
{
    $filename = $list.fullname.split('/') | select -Last 1
    $newfile =$filename.FullName.split(".")[0] + $i + ".xml"
    $object.DownloadFile($list, $newfile)
    $i +=1
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this produced several errors: 'Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At line:9 char:5
+     $object.DownloadFile($list, $newfile)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:7 char:5
+     $filename = $list.fullname.split('/') | select -Last 1
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
'